# Kaltura account settings error

Tags: azure, key, account, azure-media-services, kaltura

I have Kaltura CE on Microsoft Azure but when I fill in Microsoft Azure Media Service Account Name & Microsoft Azure Media Service Access Key on the account settings page I get the following error:"Invalid enumeration value '0' for parameter 'type', expecting enumeration type 'KalturaPartnerType'".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same but solved it entering to that settings tab from the http://.cloudapp.net/admin_console, Publishers, choose publisher, Actions, Manage. That opens a new browser window, and from that one, you should be able to configure your Azure Media Services settings.

Answer (score 1):

Try to follow installation instructions from https://github.com/Akvelon2014/Media-Management-based-on-Kaltura